# Laravel get instance in a model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, instance

First please be gentle i am a beginner and im only coding for practise.

I try to pass an instance to the model but i always get this error

```
Argument 1 passed to Store::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem, none given
```

my model

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem as File;

class Store extends Eloquent
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function __construct(File $file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

}
```

Could please somebody tell me what i am doing wrong?

thank you

**EDIT**

I just used simply like this in my Controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $store = new Store;
        return View::make('store', $store);
    }
```

Comment: `new Store;` you're not passing a `File` instance, and the constructor expects one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `File` class is one of Laravels Facades, which means you do not need to pass it into your models construct.

You can access it from anywhere in Laravel using `File::someMethod()`. If you use namespaces then you have to access via the root namespace `\File::someMethod()`.

Within your `store` view you can access the `File` facade directly with the aforementioned method.

Take a look at the documentation on the file system here http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Filesystem.Filesystem.html

So you can use `File::copy()` without having to instantiate a class as it is called from a static method.

Comment: you misunderstood, i am not needing the input file, i am needing the FileSystem for creading folders and manipulating files, such as appending content to it: http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Filesystem.Filesystem.html

Comment: maybe it should be better if i would call it in the controller instead of the model

Comment: Yeah I got the link wrong that is what I was referring to, `File` is basically an alias to this class.

Comment: No problem, you should take a look at the core Laravel files in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate`. You will get a better understanding of how the framework operates.